# RSpec - testing with cancan views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cancan

I have a simple test like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Evaluating Questions" do

    before do
        puts "before"
        @john = FactoryBot.create(:admin_user)
        login_as(@john, :scope => :admin_user)
        FactoryBot.create(:question)
        QuestionStatus.create!(name: "Approved")
        visit questions_path
    end


    scenario "A user evaluates a question correctly" do
        puts "scenario"
        visit questions_path
        click_link "Evaluate"
        select('Approved', :from => 'revision_history_question_status_id')

        click_button "Create Revision history"
        expect(page).to have_content("Question was successfully reviewed")
    end


end
```

The problem is that "Evaluate" link is only showed if the user has the permission from cancan. But that user I'm creating on my factory has the permission. But still, rspec can't find the link on the page, so I guess it's not being rendered. Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks

EDIT:

Rspec error message:
    Failure/Error: click_link "Evaluate"

```
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find visible link "Evaluate"
```

Comment: @MarkMerritt done

Comment: Can you use `RSpec.feature "Evaluating Questions", js: true do` to run tests in browser to see if link is not visible for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Found what was wrong: I should be using `:scope => :user`. Before, it wasn't able to sign in so that was why it couldn't find the link